# How do I use the | and > characters in ruby Open3?

Tags: ruby

The following works and gives me the output I receive had I typed `ifconfig` in the linux terminal:

```
Open3.popen2("ifconfig") do |stdin, stdout, thread|
  stdin.close

  stdout.each_line do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
```

Now, I'd like to grep those lines:

```
Open3.popen2("ifconfig", "|", "grep", "192") do |stdin, stdout, thread|
  stdin.close

  stdout.each_line do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
```

When typing 'ifconfig | grep 192' directly in my terminal I get:
    `inet 192.168.1.183  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255`

But in ruby I get:
    `grep: Unknown host`

Why can't I pipe in Ruby? Similar things happen when I try to use ">".

Comment: If you simply pass `|` as you did, it just gets interpreted as an argument (it's as if you ran `ifconfig \| grep 192` from the command line). I believe you'd have to open different processes with popen and connect the pipes if you want to use grep. The other option is to simply use ruby to filter the output

Comment: You’re using shell constructs. `Open3` might provide a separate function to give a shell command, but you should also be able to do `popen2("sh", "-c", "ifconfig | grep 192")` anyway. (Actually, NullUserException’s new addition about using Ruby to replace `grep 192` is probably better.)

Comment: Of course the other option is to simply use the [backticks](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Kernel.html#method-i-60) (`output=\`ifconfig | grep 192\``) and then do whatever you need to do with `output`. Be wary of the pitfalls of using this method (e.g.: possible execution of arbitrary code if you pass user input)